# Cheap second-hand bookstores/antiquaries in Budapest

Tags: shopping, budapest

I am looking for places to buy cheap book (dictionaries) in Budapest. Last time I was there none of the places I found through Google Maps was there (so I only visited Vonnegut Antikvárium), and I am only gonna be there very briefly, so I would appreciate places you know in person.

Also, what is the word for a second-hand bookstore in Hungarian – “antikvárium”? I found régiségbolt, but it seems to mean antique shop with furniture and so forth.

Comment: Close voter: This question is not about price shopping. It's about finding something hard to find. There were lots of new book shops last time I was in Budapest. Finding old books was another story. In some cities such places are easy to find, in other places you really need expert help.

Comment: Except that searching "best used bookstores in Budapest" returns a few helpful looking links including one from [Budapest.com](http://www.budapest.com/things_to_do/shopping/books.en.html)

Comment: There is also Evelyn Leeper's lists of bookstores. Budapest has a few listed (some have latest info from 2008): http://leepers.us/evelyn/bookshops/eu-misc.htm#budapest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nyugat Antikvárium

[image]
Has been in business for many years, as it was founded in 1990. Supposedly has a very wide selection covering a variety of eras and topics.

<sup>1054 Bajcsy Zsilinszky u. 34</sup>

<sup>Phone: 061 / 311- 90-23</sup>

<sup>Monday - Friday 10-17:30</sup>

## Font Antikvárium

[image]

Founded in 1991. Apparently has a helpful staff.

<sup>1062 Budapest, Andrássy út 56th</sup>

## Pesti Forrás Antikvárium

[image]

This shop appears to boast a special selection in history books and books about science. It has books that are more than a century old and also features old postcards and photographs.

<sup>1062 Budapest, Aradi utca 28.</sup>

<sup>Phone: 061-708-9863</sup>

<sup>Monday: *8-16.* Tuesday - Wednesday: *12-18* Thursday: *12-20 * Friday: *12-18*</sup>

## Szőnyi Antikvárium

[image]

Apparently well organized as well as carrying a wide variety of books.

<sup>1055 Budapest Szent István krt. 3</sup>

<sup>Phone: 06 1 /  311-6431</sup>

<sup>Monday - Friday: *10-18* Saturday: *9-13*</sup>

## Antikvár.hu

[image]

Supposedly has "really helpful, youthful and helpful staff".

<sup>1053 Budapest, Museum Boulevard 39</sup>

<sup>Phone: +36 1266 -2653</sup>

<sup>Monday - Friday: *10-18*. Saturday: *10-13*</sup>

---

Attribution: I have mostly used a [single source](http://welovebudapest.com/elmeny.kultura/top.5.antikvarium.budapesten). I have never been to Budapest, and have no personal experience with these shops.