# Cheap second-hand bookstores/antiquaries in Belgrade

Tags: shopping, belgrade

I am looking for places to buy cheap book (dictionaries) in Belgrad. And I am only going to be there very briefly (travelling through the city), so I would appreciate places you know and not far off from the motorway/main streets.

Also, is “антикварница” the word for a second-hand bookstore in Serbian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheap second-hand bookstores/antiquaries in Budapest](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76671/cheap-second-hand-bookstores-antiquaries-in-budapest)

Comment: @Henrik Budapest and Belgrade are certainly not the same city, even those both start with a B

Comment: @Henrik defo not a duplicate, especially that I specifically refer to Hungarian and Serbian, respectively – I just do this in every city I happen to visit. But thanks for your vigilance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [news page](http://www.knjizaramagelan.com/novosti.html) for [Magellan Bookstore](http://www.knjizaramagelan.com/index.html) translated via google:

> 05/20/2016.  Bookstore MAGELAN the requirements of its users will not
>   close the door during the summer season. Bookstore will operate at
>   full capacity during the summer months of July and August.

The store sells books in [English and Serbian](http://www.knjizaramagelan.com/english.html):

> Magellan Bookshop is second-hand bookshop based in centre of Belgrade,
>   Serbia. It is probably the only second-hand bookshop selling titles in
>   English language continuously in this part of the world. It has great
>   selection of books, in Serbian and English, especially in areas of:
>   biography, travel & exploration, classics fiction, literary criticism,
>   art, religion, philosophy, psychology and history.  Opening times:
>   Monday to Friday 12-20, Saturday 10-14.

There is a google [streetmap view](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@44.8005586,20.4710315,3a,42.8y,204.55h,87.75t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sBsDSeTI8T7zKIt4G6TaJnQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) from 2013

антикварница appears to just be an antique shop according to a web search, rather than a second hand bookstore. I'm afraid I'm not sure what the correct translation should be.

Comment: Cool, thanks – the catalogue was a bit disappointing, but I will pay them a visit anyway.

Comment: @iyoossaev At least if you go there they'll be able to point you at other places or even phone for you if they don't have what you want

Comment: Will keep that in mind – I just hope I will have time for that.